# MySql x rows with x-1 similar columns, combine last column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, row

I have a mysql table that has several values like this

```
id    name  number  value
------------------------------------
1     John    3      blue
1     John    3      red
1     John    3      green
2     Aly     2      red
2     Aly     2      blue
3     Sam     1      green
4     Tiad    6      white
5     Krix    5      orange
```

Is there a SQL command that can group by or combine these values into one row, with the final column's values put into that one row as values separated by commas? So basically, what command could take the above table and change it into

```
id    name  number  value
------------------------------------
1     John    3      blue, red, green
2     Aly     2      red, blue
3     Sam     1      green
4     Tiad    6      white
5     Krix    5      orange
```

Is there such a command?

Comment: which RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try sommething like this

**Updated:**

```
SELECT id,name,number, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') AS value

 FROM yourtable GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Will this return all the column values in addition to the concatenated one? I'm in the process of testing it out, but I only ask because I don't see the command selecting the number column anywhere so how would this work?

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the help friend. It worked exactly as intended. :D